# Activity XML symbol cannot be resolved in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to add a new empty activity to my app. When I generate the new activity and open the .java file, there is already an error in the pre-generated code.

```
public class Brief2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brief2);
    }
}
```

On the setContentView line, the "activity_brief2" is returning the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_brief2'

The issue is that i have another .java file for another activity with the exact same code that works just fine:

```
public class Brief1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brief1);
```

The .xml file for `brief2` is created and has the exact same set-up as the .xml file for `brief1`, but for some reason it doesn't work. I've tried retyping it but it didn't work. I am very new to this (started learning yesterday) and the places I've looked online aren't giving me something that works.

I've tried deleting the original .xml that was generated with the activity, then using the context action on the `activity_brief2` to generate a new .xml file, but that still did nothing. How do I fix this?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project (look in the Build menu), and if that doesn't work, do Invalidate Caches/Restart (in the File menu). There's apparently some issue with a recent version of Android Studio that glitches when a new layout is created.

Comment: Do I lose any of my code if I clean/rebuild the project, or do the cache thing?

Comment: Nope. Those just tell Android Studio to clean up its own internal files.

Comment: The Invalidate Caches and Restart option worked! Thank you very much, saved me a lot of headache.